# Using a selection tool will select everything

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, select

When I use the Selected Features tool and try to drag a box around a few small items it grabs everything.  If i use the edit tool it will correctly select only features that are inside/intersect the bounding box.  I'm using arc 10.2.2 on SDE.

Comment: Are these features parts of the same MULTIPOLYGON feature?

Answer (score 1):

Right click the layer and select "Properties..." to open the "Layer Properties" window. Select the "Source" tab and check to see if the "Geometry Type:" is "Multipoint" or a similar type of geometry. If so than there will be multiple points/polygons that correspond to one record and will result in the behavior you describe.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the MXD was just corrupt.  I remade my mxd and everything worked fine.  There were only lines and points.